# Serving static files in Electron (React app)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am working on a project where I need to build a desktop app in Electron. The majority of functionality will be built in React, but there will be a part where we need to integrate a 3rd party static HTML magazine. I need some advice on how to do this. I am building a proof of concept app currently and I have based it on this https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

how would I add that on /static/ I server static HTML files. I know I could do it in express, but I really don't want to include the entire express framework just for serving static files.

I was looking at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static but have no Idea how to integrate it in my react app and bundle it into electron app.

Comment: Hey @ales, I'd like to know that the below answer works for you? On development mode, I'm using web pack give me error "can't find module react", mean module resolve issue while without intercept protocol it works, any idea?

Answer (score 31):

I found another solution without using `express` or `serve-static`, we only 
need to cusomize Electron built-in `interceptFileProtocol()` to serve static contents.

**Code**:(main.js)

(I use the [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) as Electron template)

```
function createWindow () {
  window = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })
  window.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: 'index.html',    /* Attention here: origin is path.join(__dirname, 'index.html') */
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true
  }))

  window.on('closed', () => {
    window = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', () => {
  protocol.interceptFileProtocol('file', (request, callback) => {
    const url = request.url.substr(7)    /* all urls start with 'file://' */
    callback({ path: path.normalize(`${__dirname}/${url}`)})
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) console.error('Failed to register protocol')
  })
  createWindow()
})
```

**Reference**:
[protocol.interceptFileProtocol()](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/protocol.md#protocolinterceptfileprotocolscheme-handler-completion)

**Explaination**:

- Normally, if you run React app as a normal website, all static contents should be served by `HTTP [GET]` method. Though they use relative paths, your HTTP server will handle the path parsing work.
- However, when running under Electron, things change.
- Your static contents usually use relative path like `./picture.jpg`, Electron will use `file` protocol instead of `HTTP` protocol and find the file under root path like `C://.//`. So static contents like `./picture.jpg` won't be loaded correctly.
- By customizing `interceptFileProtocol()`, all static contents' requests will be pointed to your working directory instead of Windows(or other OS) root.

Finally, I'm not sure whether it's a good solution for all Electron projects, but if you already have a `React` project (or some other SPA) and want to wrap it with Electron, this solution would be fine to use.

Comment: This worked for me, but then I had trouble requiring my index js file in index.html using relative paths. Ended up requiring it using an absolute, by getting app path with `require('electron').remote.app.getAppPath()`

Comment: Where u added it @ChrisDolphin? I with a big problem here, works fine with dev mode but after pack the app doesn't work, driving me crazy

Comment: Works here, i changed the url = path.join(require('electron').remote.app.getAppPath(), WEB_FOLDER, url), thanks, works when packing the app

Comment: Works here, i changed the url = path.join(require('electron').remote.app.getAppPath(), WEB_FOLDER, url), thanks, works when packing the app

Comment: On development mode, serving using webpack give me error "can't find module react", mean module resolve issue while without intercept protocol it works, any idea  ?

Comment: Couple points: 1. would be nicer to incorporate all the imports etc. like @zgue showed. 2. another problem I ran into is that it only works like this if webpack html template does _not_ inject the hash - so make sure that's off ;)

Comment: Hi, I found it easier to create a custom `app` protocol so it does not interfere with `file://`, using `registerFileProtocol` (syntax is identical to `interceptFileProtocol`). Also you may need to remove the query param of URL for URLs like `app://foobar.js?version=2`, you should drop the `?version=2`. It was useful for me to install MathJax in an Electron app for example.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to the great answer from @yeze322 above, here a working sample for all not so familiar with node and electron (like me). It took me some time to find out the correct require statements.

main.js (code from @yeze322 plus required imports)

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, protocol } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: 'index.html',    /* Attention here: origin is path.join(__dirname, 'index.html') */
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true
  }))

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', () => {
  protocol.interceptFileProtocol('file', (request, callback) => {
    const url = request.url.substr(7)    /* all urls start with 'file://' */
    callback({ path: path.normalize(`${__dirname}/${url}`) })
  }, (err) => {
    if (err) console.error('Failed to register protocol')
  })
  createWindow()
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Comment: Nothing personal - but this should really just be a comment on @yeze322's answer. I spent a bit of time looking between the two answers trying to figure out which I should use ;)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use this to run a Blazor WebAssembly app through Electron. After making the Blazor WebAssembly app into static files.

Answer (score 1):

In your main file you have

```
const app = require("app")
app.on("ready", () => {
  ...
```

Here you can start the server like you would do in node.js

```
  const serveStatic = require('serve-static')
  // or
  const express = require('express')
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Putting 3rd patry resources in the resources directory can solve the problem